# Spring Authentication filter not working

Tags: spring, authentication, filter

I am implementing custom authentication filter as below. But it always returns 404 not found. For Ex: http://localhost:8082/InstaHelpers/api/user/registration.

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
 @Configuration
                    @EnableWebSecurity
                    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
                        public static final String JWT_TOKEN_HEADER_PARAM = "X-Authorization";
                        public static final String FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/auth/login";
                        public static final String TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/**";
                        public static final String TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT = "/api/auth/token";

                        @Autowired
                        private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
                        @Autowired
                        private JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
                        @Autowired
                        private JwtAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;
                        @Autowired
                        private AjaxAuthenticationProvider ajaxAuthenticationProvider;
                        @Autowired
                        private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

                        @Autowired
                        private TokenExtractor tokenExtractor;

                        @Autowired
                        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

                        private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

                        protected AjaxLoginProcessingFilter buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
                            AjaxLoginProcessingFilter filter = new AjaxLoginProcessingFilter(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT, successHandler,
                                    failureHandler, objectMapper);
                            filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
                            return filter;
                        }

                        protected JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
                            List<String> pathsToSkip = Arrays.asList(TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT, FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT);
                            SkipPathRequestMatcher matcher = new SkipPathRequestMatcher(pathsToSkip, TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT);
                            JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(failureHandler,
                                    tokenExtractor, matcher);
                            filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
                            return filter;
                        }

                        @Bean
                        @Override
                        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
                            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
                            auth.authenticationProvider(ajaxAuthenticationProvider);
                            auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                            http.csrf().disable() // We don't need CSRF for JWT based authentication
                                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)

                                    .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

                                    .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Login
                                                                                                                        // end-point
                                    .antMatchers(TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Token
                                                                                        // refresh
                                                                                        // end-point
                                    .antMatchers("/console").permitAll() // H2 Console Dash-board -
                                                                            // only for testing
                                    .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).authenticated() // Protected
                                                                                                                            // API
                                                                                                                            // End-points
                                    .and().addFilterBefore(new CustomCorsFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                                    .addFilterBefore(buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                                    .addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),
                                            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
                        }
                    }
```

Web.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-
                security-4.2.xsd">


                <context-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
                </context-param>


                <listener>
                    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
                </listener>


                <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
                    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                    <init-param>
                        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet- context.xml</param-value>
                    </init-param>
                    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
                </servlet>

                <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>
             </web-app>
```

Dependencies

```
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
```

I am aware solution to such issue is listed in other questions but it is not solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either create class which extends **AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer** it will load the **springSecurityFilterChain** automatically.

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

or provide spring security filter chain in **web.xml** like below

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

( I can also notice one space in **servlet- context.xml**, correct this as well).

Other thing you might have incorrect mapping in your **view resolver**, kindly post code for that as well

Comment: I have been banging my head off the desk for the past three days trying to get something similar working!

Thank you so much ... unfortunately all you get is an up-vote.